# Display events in weekly calendar (Rails3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want create a weekly calendar, that will show events. I'am looking for a start idea, how can I list elements.
I store database the event name, date, start_time, end_time etc.

Answer (score 3):

Will a monthly calendar work for you?  There's [a Rails plugin for that](http://dev.elevationblog.com/2009/07/23/event-calendar-rails-plugin/).

Here's a screen shot, taken [from this post](http://dev.elevationblog.com/2009/07/23/event-calendar-rails-plugin/):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check out [fullcalendar_rails](https://github.com/vinsol/fullcalendar_rails), which has daily, weekly and monthly views.

Demo [here](http://fullcalendar.vinsol.com/).